# createElement script ,async=false，don't work

Tags: javascript

createElement script ,async=false，don't work

```
<script>
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'a.js';
        script.async = false;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        console.log(a);   //  undefined
</script>
```

a.js is just var a = 123;createElement script is async default,so i use async=false,but it look like don't work

Comment: It doesn’t seem like this could ever work. Why not simply use [modules](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) instead?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `<script>` elements that are not ["parser inserted"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#parser-inserted) have their [*force async*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script-force-async) flag set to true. Setting the `async` attribute will set that flag to `false`, but then, it will be either *async* per the attribute, or [it will only make it](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script-processing-model:parser-inserted-5) appended in [*the list of scripts that will execute in order as soon as possible*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#list-of-scripts-that-will-execute-in-order-as-soon-as-possible) instead of in [*the set of scripts that will execute as soon as possible*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#set-of-scripts-that-will-execute-as-soon-as-possible). This will ensure that if you do load another script that way, they'll load in the order you defined, but they will still be loaded in parallel.

You can however add a `load` event handler on your `<script>` to wait until it's properly loaded.

```js
const el = document.createElement("script");
el.src = "https://app.requestly.io/delay/2000/https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js";
el.async = false;
el.onload = (evt) => console.log(typeof jQuery);
document.body.append(el);
```

Comment: thank you ,onload is ok .but i have other question: I have a react app,in index.html,sometimes I need load a js before bundle.js . how can I  do ?

Comment: I edited my answer, setting `async` to false still does have an influence, namely it will force the loading of various scripts that had that property set to false to be loaded in order they were inserted. So you'd set both "a.js"'s and "bundle.js"'s  `async` to false, and make sure to append *a* before *bundle*.

Comment: but it look like webpack can't set bundle.js to load with `async=false`......in webpack output,maybe I don't find