# Is the dynamic inject `<script />` tag considered async?

Tags: javascript

There is a lot of third-party code like this:

## Method 1

```js
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

And because the `<script />` tag has a `async` feature, it may rewrite it as follows:

## Method 2

```html
<script async src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js" />
```

My current question is that I understand that method 2, a script tag with an async property will always be async and will not block other requests, but what about the method 1? Will other scripts be able to load once the DOM injects the script tag and begins loading script?

Comment: "_but what about the first one?_": I only see one script tag in your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75382411/1).

Comment: @mplungjan access window.FB will return undefined after method 1, which is why I'm wondering if it's async or not, because it behaves async, but I'm not sure if it will prevent other scripts from loading.

Comment: @jsejcksn I've edit the post to be more clear.

Comment: The questions are a bit different but I believe [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74595472/3702797) would answer your question quite correctly...

Comment: If you create and inject dynamically 2 `script` tags - I believe that they will be fetched simultaneously (asynchronously) on the network level, but will be parsed and executed sequentially (synchronously) unless they have the `async` attribute set before they have been injected into the DOM.

Comment: @IVOGELOV actually it's the other way around, you **need to set** their `async` flag to false for the order to be maintained, (that's because they have the flag set to true automatically).

Comment: @Kaiido I've link the question to your previous answer

Comment: @Kaiido You are right, `document.createElement("script")` sets the `async` attribute to TRUE by default.